# what is the meaning of FTP attributes in Filewatcher Property file?

Tags: ftp, file-watcher

The Properties file of a file watcher contains many attributes. I was not able to find the use of certain attributes. The attributes are

FTPModeBinary and 
FTPConnectionPASV

these take true or false as its value.

Can anyone please help me to understand the use of these attributes?

Answer (score 0):

"Binary" (as opposed to "text") transfers the file exactly as-is without doing any end-of-line conversions (like LF to CR/LF).

"Passive" means that the FTP server always opens a listening socket for the data connection and the client connects to it.  (FTP uses a separate TCP channel for the actual data transfer.)  Traditionally, FTP would have the sender open a connection to the receiver but this began breaking when people started residing behind NAT firewalls as there's no easy way to open a connection back to the client in that case.  Without passive, it's actually possible to instruct two FTP servers to transfer a file between themselves without ever passing through the client.